# Pass datetime parameter in Web API?

Tags: c#, sql-server, datetime, asp.net-web-api

I want to ask how to pass datetime parameter in Web API, how to pass datetime parameter in optional date. I want to search in the URL can be optional date without time such as:

```
localhost:IP/api/values?date=2020-01-01
```

Expected results:

```
<ArrayOfTest xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<Test>
<UserId>341</UserId>
<Name>Emily</Name>
<Mobile>386754298</Mobile>
<Age>24</Age>
<Date>2021-11-06T16:04:00</Date>
</Test>
<Test>
<UserId>2555</UserId>
<Name>Peter</Name>
<Mobile>48295729</Mobile>
<Age>45</Age>
<Date>2020-10-12T20:35:00</Date>
</Test>
```

It can found out date after 2020-01-01. some value are null from SQL Server database, so I used `dbnull` to make sure the code works and I didn't use Entity Framework to connect the database, I have try to just pass datetime parameter in get method and it is not work as well. Is it possible to pass datatime parameter like this way?

Class code:

```
    public class TestClass
    {

        public string UserId { get; set; }

        public string Name { get; set; }

        public string Mobile { get; set; }

        public int Age { get; set; }

        public DateTime? Date { get; set; }
    }
```

controller code:

```
        public IHttpActionResult Get(DateTime date)
        {
            List<UserClass> Test = new List<UserClass>();
            string mainconn = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["myconn"].ConnectionString;
            SqlConnection sqlconn = new SqlConnection(mainconn);
            string sqlquery = "SELECT UserID, Name, Mobile, Age, Date From tbluser where Date="+date;
            sqlconn.Open();
            SqlCommand sqlcomm = new SqlCommand(sqlquery, sqlconn);
            SqlDataReader reader = sqlcomm.ExecuteReader();
            while (reader.Read())
                {
                    Test.Add(new UserClass()
                    {
                        UserId = reader.GetValue.ToString(0),
                        Name = reader.GetValue.ToString(1),
                        Mobile = reader.GetValue.ToString(2),
                        Access = Convert.ToInt32(reader.GetValue(3)),
                        Date = Convert.ToDateTime(reader.GetValue(4))
                    });
                }
            return Ok(Test);
        }
```

Comment: What database engine are you using?

Comment: ssms database which i am using it now

Comment: what version of SQL Server are you using? For instance in 2022 (v16) there is a new `DATETRUNC` function that helps for this very query

Comment: 2018 which i am using it now

Comment: @ChrisSchaller Interesting! But is `DATETRUNC` SARGable?

Comment: @Dai no it is not, it will still result in an _INDEX SCAN_ if you applied it to the indexed value, instead you would apply `DATETRUNC` to the comparison value. Using `BETWEEN` or `>= ... AND ... <` against a Date/Time/2/Offset column will use _Index Search Arguments_ (_INDEX SEEK_) at the cost of 3 reads per row. (still better than 2 reads of _INDEX SCAN_) The end result will be more standard and efficient than the `DATEADD(DATEDIFF())` style logic we used in the past to truncate dates. But it wouldn't surprise me if they optimise this in the future to improve Time-Series queries.

Comment: @ChrisSchaller I honestly can't think of a good reason to truncate or rebuild (`DATEFROMPARTS`) a date/time value though - e.g. a predicate to find rows with dates in a given month is the same as a range query - and when doing group-by-month I'd just use `GROUP BY YEAR(dt), MONTH(dt)` as two separate columns instead of things like `SELECT dt, DATETRUNCT( month, dt ) AS mo FROM ... GROUP BY mo`.

Comment: @ChrisSchaller Also, you'd think the whole point of a deterministic function like `DATETRUNC( mo, dt )` would be precisely to allow the DB enigne to convert that non-SARGable scan to a range predicate: `WHERE DATETRUNC( month, dt ) = @monthParam` can be transformed to `WHERE dt >= @monthParam AND dt < DATEADD( month, 1, @monthParam )` (the `DATEADD(...)` part is a const-expresssion so it's fully sargable... right?

Comment: When written like that yes, but the engine doesn't do this (Obvious) translation _yet_. It's so intuitive that I absolutely expect this to be added in the near future, but I just ran some tests on the latest preview build, we still have to transpose the comparison ourselves. It is if nothing else a step in the right direction... Right now, we could write a middleware to intercept and parse the SQL query ourselves now that there is a standard function implementation to target :) If I can do it, I hope someone at MS is already working on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using string concatenation to build your query, it is recommended that you use ISO date format for dates:

In C# we can use the `u` format specifier to obtain an ISO date for SQL, but it appends the value with a `Z`, the following is a simple way to use this in strings:

```
date.ToString("u").TrimEnd('Z');
```

That is equivalent to:

```
date.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
```

But now we have a problem, does the incoming *date* parameter represent a whole *day*, or a specific point in *time* (for the purposes of this query)? Your request is that we want to specify the *Date* only, without time, for that we can use this format:

```
date.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")
```

Now we have a new problem, in SQL if your data contains *time* values, then you need to truncate the data to just the *date* component, to pickup all the values for the provided date.

So now your query looks like this:

```
string sqlquery = @"SELECT UserID, Name, Mobile, Age, Date 
                    FROM tbluser 
                    WHERE Cast([Date] as Date) = '"+date.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")+"'";
```

Using a function in the `where` clause makes this a non-SARGable query, which is hard for the database to optimise, you will generally get better performance by using a `BETWEEN` and passing in a value for the `date` and the date of the next day:

```
string sqlquery = @"SELECT UserID, Name, Mobile, Age, Date 
                    FROM tbluser 
                    WHERE [Date] BETWEEN '"+date.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")+"' AND '"+date.AddDays(1).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")+"'";
```

> **[SARGable functions in SQL Server](https://blogs.msmvps.com/robfarley/2010/01/21/sargable-functions-in-sql-server/#:%7E:text=SARGable%20is%20an%20adjective%20in%20SQL%20that%20means,%E2%80%93%20SARGable%20is%20short%20for%20Search%20ARGument%20Able.)**
> SARGable is an adjective in SQL that means that an item can be found using an index (assuming one exists). Understanding SARGability can really impact your ability to have well-performing queries. Incidentally – SARGable is short for Search ARGument Able.

But now this query is a bit of a mess, instead we should use *parameters* to pass through the value, this way we do not need to be aware of ISO dates and formats, the ADO.Net runtime will deal with this for us.

> Parameterizing queries offers other benefits, like SQL Injection prevention through input sanitization and other processing optimizations

Lets change the query to use parameters:

```
string sqlquery = @"SELECT UserID, Name, Mobile, Age, Date 
                    FROM tbluser 
                    WHERE Date BETWEEN @fromDate AND @toDate";
```

Then you need to pass the *dates* to the `SqlCommand` as a parameter,

> notice here that we are using the `.ToDate()` method on the `DateTime` object to trim the *time* portion that the user *might* have provided.

```
SqlCommand sqlcomm = new SqlCommand(sqlquery, sqlconn);
sqlcomm.Parameters.Add("@fromDate ", SqlDbType.Date);
sqlcomm.Parameters["@fromDate "].Value = date.Date;
sqlcomm.Parameters.Add("@toDate ", SqlDbType.Date);
sqlcomm.Parameters["@toDate "].Value = date.AddDays(1).Date;
```

This is a good post for comparing string concatenated SQL with parameterized queries: [C#: SQL Injection Protection Using Parameterized Queries](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/53105.c-sql-injection-protection-using-parameterized-queries.aspx)

> **UPDATE**
> See this fiddle for a live demo: https://dotnetfiddle.net/8zLLrR

---

Because your controller is pre-sanitizing the input and constraining it to a `DateTime` typed value, SQL Injection is not likely to be an issue in this *specific* example, however the *string-concatenation* approach to build your query is generally a *red flag* in Web API as this is where your code is most vulnerable to external inputs.

SQL Server has an optimization where it tries to re-use execution plans when queries are re-executed. You will notice in SSMS when you run a query the first time, it is almost always slower than the second time if you re-execute the same query. That is because it has an internal table of stored execution plans and the `SQL` that you submit is the main key to this *index*.

When the date filter changes, if you use string concatenation this results in a different `SQL` so it is harder for the database engine to lookup an existing query execution plan, and in many cases it will generate a new one. When we use parameters, the actual `SQL` query is the same each time, so the optimizer can simply lookup any previously saved execution plans.

> Later versions of SQL Server have additional optimisations to automatically parameterise query expressions for the execution plan index, but it's not 100% and not an excuse to be lazy developers ;)

Comment: I had to re-write this post, SQL Injection is not a real issue here, but the date filtering and string formatting are the main issues to focus on.

Comment: Sorry about that, missed that when I switched languages... It's just `DateTime.Date` (so just `.Date`. I've updated the post and included a fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/8zLLrR

Answer (score 0):

You should **not** add a string like this

```
SELECT UserID, Name, Mobile, Age, Date From tbluser where Date="+date+"
```

This may cause **SQL injection**. Instead, follow this documentation using SQL parameters with type Date
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.parameters?view=dotnet-plat-ext-6.0

Here is the example:

```
        string sqlquery = "SELECT UserID, Name, Mobile, Age, Date From tbluser where Date= @YourDate";
        SqlCommand sqlcomm = new SqlCommand(sqlquery, sqlconn);
        sqlcomm.Parameters.Add("@YourDate", SqlDbType.Date);
        sqlcomm.Parameters["@YourDate"].Value = date;
```

Comment: You beat me to it ;) to help new devs, please use the same names for parameters that were used in the original post, that will help them to understand how your solution specifically applies to them.

Comment: Thank you for your advice :) I edited my comment using the same names as his parameters.

Comment: so my string will get sql injection if i run it, is it right?

Comment: Yes, when you concat string like that. It will be easy to have a SQL injection attack.
you can read more about SQL Injection in here https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_injection.asp

Comment: The issue with this solution is that it does not address the requirement to filter for the date ignoring _time_.